# Closure compiler required entry point "..." never provided

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler

I have a js module depending on a couple of other modules. I want to avoid using browserify in order to build CommonJS modules, because it’s badly gets on with closure compiler minification.
I’m trying to compile module via closure compiler like so:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js=node_modules/object-id/index.js --js=node_modules/each-csv/index.js --js=node_modules/matches-selector/index.js --js=index.js --process_common_js_modules --common_js_entry_module=index.js
```

Everything I get is an error:

```
ERROR - required entry point "module$each_csv" never provided

ERROR - required entry point "module$matches_selector" never provided

ERROR - required entry point "module$object_id" never provided

3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

What is the proper way to use processing of commonjs modules in closure compiler?

Comment: Are you trying to produce Node code or browser code?  Also what version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: I used both the latest and v20140814.
Ideally, I want to produce browser code (replace browserify), but compiled package would be ok too.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but have you see:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/closure-npc

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I’ve come up with is a non-wrapping CommonJS merger - [UncommonJS](https://github.com/dfcreative/uncommon).
It merges all the dependable modules in the proper order from the passed entry file into a single one-scoped bundle, resolving global vars interference, replacing `module.exports` and `require` declarations and removing duplicates, so that result is ~27% better compressable via closure compiler than a browserify bundle.